# Using functions for doing calculations

Tags: python

I have to make the calculations using the functions which I am facing difficulty with.

Formulas for the calculation:

Earnings/loss: `(value-price)*share`

Yearly Earning/Loss in % `= ((value-price)/price)/(current date- purchase date))*100`

```
stocks = [
    { 'symbol': 'GOOGLE', 'share': 125, "price": 772.88, 'value': 941.53,'Purchase Date':"8-1-2015" },
    { 'symbol': 'MSFT', 'share': 85, "price": 56.60, 'value': 73.04 ,'Date':"8-1-2015"},
    { 'symbol': 'RDS-A', 'share': 400, "price": 49.58, 'value': 55.74 ,'Purchase Date':"8-1-2015"},
{ 'symbol': 'AIG', 'share': 235, "price": 54.21, 'value': 65.27 ,'Date':"8-1-2015"},
    { 'symbol': 'FB', 'share': 150, "price": 124.31, 'value':172.45,'Purchase Date':"8-1-2015" },
    { 'symbol': 'M', 'share': 425, "price": 30.30, 'value': 23.98 ,'Purchase Date':"1-10-2017"},
    { 'symbol': 'F', 'share': 85, "price": 150.37, 'value': 145.30,'Date':"2-17-2017" },
    { 'symbol': 'IBM', 'share': 80, "price": 150.37, 'value': 145.30,'Purchase Date':"5-12-2017"}
]


print('Stock ownership for Bob Smith')
print('-----------------------------------------')
print('Stock          Share #            Earn/Lose    Date')
print('----------------------------------------')

for stock in stocks:
    earn = stock['share'] * stock['value'] - stock['share'] * stock['price']
        print(f'{stock["symbol"]}\t\t{stock["share"]}\t\t{round(earn, 2)}\t\t{stock["Date"]}')
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have to write a function that calculates two things: Earnings/Loss and Yearly EArnings/loss in %

Comment: I just have to print Symbol, Share#, EArnings/loss and Yearly earnings/loss %

Comment: But that, again, is not a question. A question ends with a question mark.

Comment: I need a solution on how to write the function for calculating the two elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the `Date` in your data means `Purchase Date`

```
stocks = [
    { 'symbol': 'GOOGLE', 'share': 125, "price": 772.88, 'value': 941.53,'Purchase Date':"8-1-2015" },
    { 'symbol': 'MSFT', 'share': 85, "price": 56.60, 'value': 73.04 ,'Purchase Date':"8-1-2015"},
    { 'symbol': 'RDS-A', 'share': 400, "price": 49.58, 'value': 55.74 ,'Purchase Date':"8-1-2015"},
{ 'symbol': 'AIG', 'share': 235, "price": 54.21, 'value': 65.27 ,'Purchase Date':"8-1-2015"},
    { 'symbol': 'FB', 'share': 150, "price": 124.31, 'value':172.45,'Purchase Date':"8-1-2015" },
    { 'symbol': 'M', 'share': 425, "price": 30.30, 'value': 23.98 ,'Purchase Date':"1-10-2017"},
    { 'symbol': 'F', 'share': 85, "price": 150.37, 'value': 145.30,'Purchase Date':"2-17-2017" },
    { 'symbol': 'IBM', 'share': 80, "price": 150.37, 'value': 145.30,'Purchase Date':"5-12-2017"}
]



df['Yearly Earning/Loss in %'] = 100*(df.value-df.price)/df.price/(pd.to_datetime('today')-pd.to_datetime(df['Purchase Date'])).dt.days
df['Earnings/loss'] = (df.value -df.price)*df.share


Purchase Date   price   share   symbol  value   Yearly Earning/Loss in %    Earnings/loss
0   8-1-2015    772.88  125 GOOGLE  941.53  0.015963    21081.25
1   8-1-2015    56.60   85  MSFT    73.04   0.021248    1397.40
2   8-1-2015    49.58   400 RDS-A   55.74   0.009089    2464.00
3   8-1-2015    54.21   235 AIG 65.27   0.014925    2599.10
4   8-1-2015    124.31  150 FB  172.45  0.028329    7221.00
5   1-10-2017   30.30   425 M   23.98   -0.024861   -2686.00
6   2-17-2017   150.37  85  F   145.30  -0.004209   -430.95
7   5-12-2017   150.37  80  IBM 145.30  -0.004702   -405.60
```

Comment: Why do you need `apply` at all?

Comment: What apply are you talking about guys? I am sorry i am new to python and having difficulties.

Comment: @YaswanthBalusu apply is a function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: @galaxyan But I haven't used apply anywhere

Comment: for stock in stocks:
    earn = stock['share'] * stock['value'] - stock['share'] * stock['price']
 print(f'{stock["symbol"]}\t\t{stock["share"]}\t\t{round(earn, 2)}\t\t{stock["Date"]}')

Comment: For the above lines of code, I am getting indentation error.

Comment: @YaswanthBalusu DYZ comment on my old answer not yours